# Firestore missing or insufficient permission firebase-rest-api python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so basically as i mentioned in title the question is im getting this error only when the database rule is set to this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

and if i use this rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

this works amazing but there is too many security risks so i decided to use the first one but in my coding am i doing something wrong plz fix me if i am

```
#initialization
app = firebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = app.auth()
db = app.firestore()

#signup method

def signUp():
    clear()
    print('Signup menu')
    print('Never forget your password or email; you will lose all your credits.\nIf this happens, contact furjack')
    email = input("Enter your email address: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")

    try:
        user_info = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
        user_id_token = user_info['idToken']

        user_wallet_ref = db.collection('users-wallet').document(email)
        user_wallet_ref.set({'wallet': 0})

        print("Successfully signed up")
        auth.send_email_verification(user_id_token)
        print('We have sent you a verification email. Please verify your email to use the app.')

        input('Press enter to continue...')

        logIn()
    except:
        print(f"Error during signup")
        input('Press enter to continue...')
        exit()
```

so this is it basically where am i doing wrong or is google wrong or wth is wrong plz help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok as no one could answer i want to share the answer as i found it very strange but yeah this answer will work

first u have to install

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

aafter installing sorry my keyboard is not working correctly.
after installing you haave to do somethings secondly go to console
click on the project setttings from the gear icon next to the project name
now dont use firestore from firebase-rest-api instead we're gonna use from firebase_admin ok are u with me now click the service settings and press generate new key or whatever it saysclick it and it will tell u to download the json file download it next to your main.py ok after that open ur main.py and import libraries like this

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

after importing we're gonna say the firebase admin to use the credentials we got from the service section in console its done like below ok

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('/path/to/jsonfile')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
```

it should be initialized like this and db will be the variable we're gonna use to take the use of ok

now lets try an example

```
user_wallet_ref = db.collection('users-wallet').document('test@gmail.com')
user_wallet_ref.set({'wallet': 0})
```

hooray when we test this time it works basically the problem was we have to use firebase_admin when we give permission to read write: if 
i think u understand what im trying to say thanks if it helped plz upvote this answer so others could get help too cuz too many pplz are looking for this solution